# how to show all mean values in the boxplot with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to add the mean values (as shown in red dots in the plot below) in the boxplot with ggplot2. I used `stat_summary` to add mean values.

However, the following plot is not the exact one that I am looking for. What I'd like to get is to show two mean values for both `Y` (blue box) and `N` (red box), not one mean value for both.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
ggplot(data = df.08.long,
      aes(x = TMT_signals, y = as.numeric(TMT_Intensities), fill = `probe.Mod.or.not(Y/N)`)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=5, color="red", fill="red") +
coord_cartesian(
  xlim = NULL,
  ylim = c(0, 2e4),
  expand = TRUE,
  default = FALSE,
  clip = "on")
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=8),
        axis.text=element_text(size=10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: A solution would be to calculate the mean outside ggplot and plot after with `geom_point`

Comment: @ViníciusFélix I thought about that, but that would be the last thing I will try. I am wondering if there is a simple solution. Why I cannot use `fill = probe.Mod.or.not(Y/N)` in the `stat_summary`, just like what I did in the `aes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## mtcars example

### Code

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(vs),drat, fill = as.factor(am)))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(
    fun=mean,
    geom="point",
    shape=21,
    size=5,
    #Define the aesthetic inside stat_summary
    aes(fill = as.factor(am)),
    position = position_dodge2(width = .75),
    show.legend = FALSE
    )
```

### Output

[image]